# How can I set the composer vendor folder to work with PhpStorm's (sync) function

Tags: composer-php, phpstorm

When I run it all that shows up is the `jp.php` file.  None of the vendor folders are present.

Comment: can you explain in detail what  is your problem?

Comment: when I try to use phpstorms "sync with [remote server]", none of the files show up in the compare window - even though I am absolutely positive there are field differences.  It is as if there is something making it ignore the files.

Comment: I've actually just started noticing this issue, too.  It didn't used to do this, but I'm currently trying to figure out why it's happening.